# Authorization middleware JWT confusion

Tags: node.js, express, security, jwt, authorization

I have a suspicion about the relative security of some authentication middleware code I came across in a course im enrolled in.

So I used postman to send a request to a protected route(see route code below) and found that I was able retrieve an order for one user with a token generated for another user.

```
const protected = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  ) {
    try {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");

  next();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  res.status(401);
  throw new Error("Not authorized, token failed");
}
 }
  if (!token) {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Not authorized, No token found");
  }
}); 
export protected
```

It seems evident to me that this middleware code will only verify if a user from decoded token exists in the DB and but will not limit access to resources based on the user/token.

```
import {addOrderItems, getOrderbyId}  from "../controllers/orderController.js";
import { protected } from "../middleware/authMiddleware.js";
    
const router = express.Router();

router.route("/").post(protected, addOrderItems);
router.route("/:id").get(protected, getOrderbyId);
//:id is the order id
```

However, when testing  another protected route for updating a user's profile info, I receive an error when using wrong token.

Was hoping for some clarification

Comment: This code, by itself, only verifies that the jwt token is valid and matches some user in the database.  It does nothing else to control what data can or cannot be accessed by that user.  BTW, what is `asyncHandler()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 Its middleware to handle exceptions inside express async functions. Check this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler).

Thanks for the clarification. Thought as much

Comment: @jfriend00 What do you think about this strategy:

I thought about adding an array field in my User DB model/document named __tokens__.
Then I would check the tokens fields for matching token. If no match in tokens field exists, throw error(not authorized)

Comment: Tokens are not necessarily forever so I wouldn't use them as the permanent key.  I don't know your app, but perhaps a record could contain a list of authorized user ids?  Or, if records belong only to one user, then each user should just have their own list of records and your server only ever looks up records that belong to the currently authorized user.  There are lots of different ways to structure things depending upon the overall needs of your app.

Answer (score 1):

jwt.verify will only verify that the given token is generated by the server or not. It doesn't care which user send this token.

For your protected middleware, it just check if the request is authorized. If so, the request will pass to the controller.

As for the updating route. It probably be something like this:

```js
// route 
router.route("/:userId", protected, updateController)

const updateController = (req, res) => {
  const user = req.user; // this is the one generated by protected middleware
  const reqUserId = req.params.userId; // this is the one send by request
  
  if (user.id !== reqUserId) {
      // if two ids are not the same, it means someone is trying
      // to update the profile with the wrong token
      res.status(401);
  }

  // update profile in database
}
```